# Integrate ASP .NET Application in Sharepoint Page Viewer with Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, authentication

I would like to integrate my own ASP .NET Application into a Sharepoint site in a Page Viewer Web Part (via URL).

My Sharepoint is accessible via: http://subdomain.domain.com

My ASP .NET Application is accessible via: http://othersubdomain.domain.com

Sharepoint and the other application are hosted on different servers.

As the sharepoint and the application should be accesible from outside of my Domain (public via Internet) I use Basic Authentication for both.

Now when I open the Sharepoint site I have to enter my user credentials once and when I navigate to my Applicaiton within sharepoint I have to enter my user credentials for the ASP .NET Application a second time (same credentials, user from a Active directory domain).

Is there a possibility to integrate my application into sharepoint without the need to sign on twice and without the need to install my application on the sharepoint server?

Thank you!